# Date Picker not working while running in azure pipeline

Tags: java, azure, selenium-webdriver, azure-pipelines, automation-testing

We have a functionality where we need to enter current date into the input field which i have given below

```
<input _ngcontent-hji-c324="" type="date" onfocus="(this.type='date')" id="plannedCompletionDate" placeholder="Planned completion date" class="ey-motif-form-control textbox-n ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty">
```

This is the method which we are using through automation

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(new Date()); // Use today date
c.add(Calendar.DATE, count); // Adding count value as days from the current date
System.out.println("Date to be added: " + count);
String output = sdf.format(c.getTime());
ReuseableFunctionalityBase.write_data_to_file(FileName, output, DataKey);
System.out.println(output);// Output is current date i.e 25-12-2023
```

This is working fine locally, But when we trigger this in azure pipeline we are getting the date inputed as different formart( Refer Screenshot)

[Different Format Date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuMuZ.png)

Not sure why this is happening only during the runs in the pipeline runs

We are expecting the date format which works fine locally

Comment: What is the expected date format you want to input? Is it **`dd-MM-yyyy`**? Did you try with a self-hosted agent installed on the local machine where the functionality can work fine? Provide the pipeline debug logs of the steps related to this functionality.

Comment: No, But I am not understanding why the date is printing as "26-12-2023" in local and printing as "02-06-122023" in self hosted agent. That is the only concern

Answer (score 0):

I have a Java program sample like as below.

```
// TestCalendar.java

import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
public class TestCalendar { 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        // creating calendar object 
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
      
        String currentDateTime = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
        System.out.println("Current date: " + currentDateTime);
      
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 2);
        String DateTime2dLater = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
        System.out.println("2 days later: " + DateTime2dLater);
      
        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 4);
        String DateTime4mLater = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
        System.out.println("4 months later: " + DateTime4mLater);
      
        calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, 2);
        String DateTime2yLater = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
        System.out.println("2 years later: " + DateTime2yLater); 
    } 
}
```

You can try to follow the above sample to update your Java code.

I have tried to compile and execute it on my local machine, in the pipeline runs on the self-hosted agents installed on the same local machine, and also in the pipeline runs on the Microsoft-hosted agents. All can work fine. All the output date are following the format (**`ddMMyyyy`**) set by the following code line.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
```

[image]

---

Comment: Hi, I have tried the above method as well and in self-hosted agent the date print likes below in console log
"20122023"
But the same gets updated to the input tag via sendkeys throws formart as "02/06/122023" not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: @AutomationTest, Did you check the date format written into the file by "**`ReuseableFunctionalityBase.write_data_to_file(FileName, output, DataKey);`**"? Is the date format correct in the file?

Comment: Yes this how it is stored in the yaml file 

PLANNED_COMPLETION_DATE: '26122023',